# Data prints out OK but still get IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python

I have a very simple data file in .csv format with one header and 12 columns of data.

However when I print out the 2nd column, the data prints out OK but I also get an **IndexError: list index out of range**.

Why is this happening?

Here is my code:

```
with open(filename, 'r',newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)    
    #read file row by row
    for row in reader:
        print(row[1])

Output:
Point
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:/Users/workspace/Python 3.5/Examples/readFile.py", line 31, in <module>
   print(row[1])

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: The last `row` of `reader` is probably an empty line or `'\n'` or something like that

Comment: Try `print(row)` to see the whole row

Comment: @Barmar There are no problems if I just print(row). IndexError: list index out of range. only occurs when I try to output a specific column

Comment: I mean use that to see why there's no `row[1]`. Before the error you should see a list that's shorter than 2 elements.

Comment: @CoryKramer Ah yes you're right... There is a  [ ] right at the end of the file. Do you have any advice on how I can remove it easily or do I have to convert the file object to a string and then split?

Comment: @bwrr Someone already posted an answer showing how to do it

Comment: You could also fix the file so it doesn't have blank lines.

Answer (score 1):

You can either handle the error with a `try/except` block:

```
with open(filename, 'r',newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)    
    #read file row by row
    for row in reader:
        try:
            print(row[1])
        except IndexError, e:
            # Do something here to alert you to the error
            print(str(e))
            print("This row has no 1st index, but here is the row...")
            print(row)
```

...or check the index first:

```
with open(filename, 'r',newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)    
    #read file row by row
    for row in reader:
        if len(row) > 1:
            print(row[1])
```